# javascript called multiple times with onchange in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a `Boot` model.  Inside `boots.js` I have the following javascript which gets called once on the first onchange event, twice the second time, three times on the third time I click on the select dropdown, etc...

I can't figure out what is happening.

**boots.js**

```
$(function() {

  $('#bootChooserControl')
    .load('/fetch_boot_style_options');

  $('#bootChooserControl').change(function(event){
    $('#productDetailPane').load(
      '/fetch_product_details',
      $(this).serialize()
    );
});
```